# How can I get the correct sum() of time fields with exact value in HH:MM:SS format

Tags: php, mysql, sum, group-concat

I used a query similar to the one below at PHPMyAdmin :

```
SELECT id, name, group_concat(timecomplete) AS 'Timelist', sum(timetaken) AS 'Total Time'
FROM dailysummarylog
```

This is what was generated on my query:

```
ID  | Name        | Timelist                   | Total Time
1   | Employee 1  |06:35:15,00:59:54,01:24:45  | 81914
2   | Employee 2  |02:44:42,00:59:36,00:15:10  | 31888
```

**Problem #1:** I used *sum()* on *Timelist* to get *Total Time* but it's not showing the correct total. The *Total Time* when I try to compute it, should have been as follows:

- **1:** 8 hours, 59 minutes, 54 seconds
- **2:** 3 hours, 59 minutes, 28 seconds

**Problem #2:** When I try to store it into another table using PHP, only the first value was shown for *Timelist* and *Total Time* for employee 2 showed "00:00:00". For employee 1, it showed "08:19:14"

**Additional Info:**
*Timelist* and *Total Time* are both set to 'Time' type.

Comment: Nobody can do anything without knowing what your data looks like. Please only ask one question at a time.

Comment: I would handle part 2 in php

Comment: In part 2, at PHP I used "mysqli_query" then INSERT INTO to generate another table having the results generated from part 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer for problem 1 use SEC_TO_TIME and TIME_TO_SEC FUNCTIONS

```
SELECT id, name, group_concat(timecomplete) AS 'Timelist', SEC_TO_TIME(sum(TIME_TO_SEC((timetaken))) AS 'Total Time'
FROM dailysummarylog group by name;
```

Comment: This solved both my first and second problem. I just set SEC_TO_TIME(sum(TIME_TO_SEC(timetaken))). Thanks a lot!